Is it possible to change radio button width when it's unselected?
I would like to have radio button lighter (less wide circle) when it's in unselected state, is there some way to change it? The first picture is what I have. The second one is what I would like to have.


This is my code:
RadioListTile(
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
            title: Text('Active'),
            value: OfferStatus.active,
            groupValue: OfferStatus.inactive,
            onChanged: (value) {},
          ),


You can use container with decoration and for animation use crossfade widget.

Not directly, no. The Radio widget is surprisingly limited when it comes to what you're able to directly theme. However, since your Radio will inevitably be in a StatefulWidget, you could toggle the visibility of the Radio entirely and render whatever widget you want. Alternatively, could could use a Stack widget to overlay another widget on top of the Radio. Finally, you could use a ShaderMask to overlay something. I can't give you the exact code, but it would look something like this:
ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
    if (isActive) {
      return const LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        stops: [
          0,
          0.75,
          0.95,
        ],
        colors: [
          Colors.white,
          Colors.white,
          Colors.transparent,
        ],
      ).createShader(bounds);
    }

    return const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white])
        .createShader(bounds);
  },
  child: Radio(),
)

Obviously, this particular shader would draw a gradient, but you could use it to draw whatever you want.

nika
fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Color.fromARGB(255, 224, 224, 224))
Have a nice coding :)

I don't want to change the color, I was asking about width
